# Compile error with variadic fucntion in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a piece of code that can't compile well.
I used variadic function and bind function together. The compiler error message show

> `error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (SimpleList::*)(int&&)>(std::_Place    holder<1>, int)>) (SimpleList&)’ slistInitter(simpleList);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::reference_wrapper<T> maybe_wrap(T& val) 
{ 
  std::cout << "this is lvalue\n";
  return std::ref(val); 
}

template<typename T>
T&& maybe_wrap(T&& val) 
{ 
  std::cout << "this is rvalue\n";
  return std::forward<T>(val); 
}

void print(){}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(const T& t, Args&&... args)
{
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
  print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

class SimpleList
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  void init(Args&&... args)
  {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    print(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template<typename SLIST>
class Collection
{
public:
  template<typename SLISTINITTER>
  void initCollection(SLISTINITTER slistInitter)
  {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    SLIST simpleList;
    slistInitter(simpleList);
  }
  template<typename... Args>
  void init(Args&&... args)
  {
    initCollection(std::bind(&SLIST::template init<Args...>, std::placeholders::_1, maybe_wrap(std::forward<Args>(args))...));
  }
};

class test
{
public:
  void work(const std::string& p1)
  {
    std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
  }
  test(){}
  test(const test&)
  {
    std::cout << "this is copy\n";
  }
  test(test&& t)
  {
    std::cout << "this is move\n";
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test& t);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test& t)
{
  os << "cool";
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  using Sample = Collection<SimpleList>;
  Sample s;
  test t;
  int i = 2;
  s.init(2);

  return 0;
}
```

If I used i as left value to pass to init function. It can compile well.

Answer (score 0):

Data members in a functor generated by `std::bind` are stored as *Lvalues*.

Taken from [std::bind reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> Member objects The return type of std::bind holds a member object of
> type std::decay::type constructed from std::forward(f), and one
> object per each of args..., of type std::decay<Arg_i>::type, similarly
> constructed from std::forward<Arg_i>(arg_i).

Your code can be reduced to:

```
struct Foo {
    template<class T>
    void Bar(T&&) {}
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    auto b = std::bind(&Foo::Bar<int>, std::placeholders::_1, 2);
    b(f);
}
```

the code doesn't compile. Passed `2` is stored as Lvalue, but we specify that signature of bounded function is `Foo::Bar(int&&)` -> takes Rvalue reference. Lvalue cannot be bounded to Rvalue. And this is the issue. As a fix, we can pass `int&` in template arguments list of `Bar` - `&Foo::Bar<int&>`.

Change in your code is `std::bind(&SLIST::template init<Args&...>`.